# woocommerce subscription switched action doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

Based on the information in woocommerce documentation:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/
The action: `woocommerce_subscription_status_changed`, 
Should be triggered also when the subscription upgraded or downgraded - `switched`,
But it only works on the following situations:
`active, on-hold, cancelled` 
Here is my sample code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_changed', 'test', 10, 3);
function test( $subscription_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $file_content = $subscription_id.' '.$old_status.' '.$new_status;
    $filename = '/tmp/test_file.txt';
    file_put_contents($filename, $file_content);
}
```

The code above works, but not when the subscription switched, my question is why ?

Comment: This seems like a good question for WooCommerce support. Perhaps the documentation is wrong.

Comment: I'll contact them anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use woocommerce_subscriptions_switch_completed action istead for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

The hook you are using

```
     add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_changed', 'test', 10, 3);  <== 2.0 or earlier
```

has become obsolete and only works in woocommerce subscription 2.0 or below.  2.0+ and above uses the following hook.

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'test', 1, 3); <=== after 2.0

 function test( $subscription_id, $old_status, $new_status ) {
     $file_content = $subscription_id.' '.$old_status.' '.$new_status;
     $filename = '/tmp/test_file.txt';
     file_put_contents($filename, $file_content);
   }
```

You can remove the global $woocommerce, as it is not longer necessary.

Comment: no no, from doc https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/action-reference/, that method carries an instance of WC_Subscription object. so it should not be $subscription_id, but $subscription object. I have read the documentation more than once

Comment: The parameters seems wrong here as per the doc
It should be 

test( $subscription_obj, $new_status , $old_status)

Comment: They work..actively using the code